# How to generate random number from exponential distribution when the sizes are the numbers of Poisson random variable in R?

Tags: r, random

Suppose we draw a random sample `y1, y2,..,y20` of size 20 from Poisson distribution with parameter 5 i.e., `y~rpois(20,5)`. Suppose we got `y1=4, y2=7, y3=5,...,y19=3, y20=5`. Then, my problem is, how to draw the samples `x1~rexp(y1,2)`, `x2~rexp(y2,2)`,...,`x20~rexp(y20,2)` so that the `sum(x)={sum(x1), sum(x2),...,sum(x20)}` which will be again a random sample?
I want to find this `sum(x)` and its mean, i.e., `mean(sum(x))` and variance ,i.e., `var(sum(x))`.

I hope my question is clear to all of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can genereate your y's with

```
y <- rpois(20,5)
```

and then you can generate your x's with

```
x <- sapply(y, rexp, rate=2)
```

and find the sum of each of these with

```
xx <- sapply(xx, sum)
```

And then find the mean and variance of the sums with

```
mean(xx)
var(xx)
```

Comment: Your code is useful. But, I am not interested in over all sum i.e., `sum(unlist(x))`. I am want to find the sample of sums i.e., `sum(x1), sum(x2),...,sum(x20)`. Then only I can find mean and variance of these sums.

Comment: Thank you so much.